# Can we configure a single node manager for multiple managed servers in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c

I have three managed servers running on a Weblogic domain. Now I need to configured node manager so that I can stop and start each of the managed servers.

My question is do I need to define a separate 'Machine' and 'Node Manager port' for each of the managed servers? Or can a single 'Machine' and "Node Manager port' combination be used to start/stop multiple managed servers

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but the configuration depends on how your Machines are distributed across your hosts on whether you need to use different ports etc. Oracle provides quite a detailed tutorial on this [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/10-NodeMgr--4472/nodemgr.htm). The contents of which is too much to replicate into SO.

I recommend you follow the tutorial and then post any specific questions you may have as a new question.

Comment: Side question, I find lot of docs which say NM is required to start/stop MS which is understandable for remote management. But, is it required even to manage a local MS? Suppose, I have an AS and MS on same machine, can't I start/stop MS from same machine without configuring to use NM?

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question. The answer though is that you can stop and start a MS from the commandline. That is what the startWeblogic scripts are for in the bin folder. However, if you want to be able to stop and start the MS from the AS, you will need to do this via the NM.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Start weblogic server and open weblogic console in browser and login with correct credential.
Step 2: Expand Environment and click on Machine link
Step 3: Click on New to add new machine and give the machine name. Then click on next.
Step 4: Enter Listen Address (server IP) and port on which node manage will run. And then click Finish.

Please use below link for more detail view
https://fi-sm.com/blog/how-to-add-new-server-on-admin-server-in-web-logic-12c-server/